# Making extension method local to the file scope

Tags: vb.net, scope, extension-methods

Currently I use the following hack to make my extensions methods local to a
file by hiding it in a uniquely named namespace. It doesn't really hide it
but as long as nobody else imports the namespace then it's cool. However
the pattern is ugly.  The below code is just to ilustrate the extension method
trick. Don't try to draw any conclusions about what I'm doing with ISubject ;)

```
MyFancyComponent.cs
```

--

```
Import MyFancyComponentMixins
Namespace MyFancyComponentMixins
    Module X
        <Extension>
        Public Function Format(s As ISubject(Of Double)) as ISubject(Of String)
            Return s.LocalizeLengthUnits().
                Select(
                parser:=Function(x) Double.Parse(x),
                formatter:=Function(x) x.ToString("0.00"))

        End Function
    End Module
End Namespace

class MyFancyComponent
    Inherits ReactiveUserControl(of MyFancyViewModel)


    Public Overrides Iterator Function  MakeReactiveBindings() as IEnumerable(of IDisposable)
        Yield Me.ViewModel.
            PropertySubject(Function(x) x.Height).
            Format().
            BindToControl(Me.HeightTextBox)
        Yield Me.ViewModel.
            PropertySubject(Function(x) x.Width).
            Format().
            BindToControl(Me.WidthTextBox)
    End Function



end class
```

Comment: The main purpose of extension methods is reuse. If they should be usable only in a single file you could simply use normal methods instead. That would make the code also more readable.

Comment: I like to use a fluent interface for these specific operations as it gets chained logically from left to right. It's a two way binding pipeline and keeping it in line aids readability. For other use cases this might not be true.

Comment: Anyway I dispute that the "main purpose of extension method is reuse". Normal functions can be reused so the point is invalid. Extensions methods allow a fluent interface as if they were instance methods. In some cases this is useful and in other cases not.

Comment: Sidenote: i didn't know that iterators were [introduced also in VB.NET now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dscyy5s0.aspx). Good to know (unfortunately i'm on VS2010). However, if `ISubject` is only used in this file and is made `Proteced` the extensions are also scoped to this file.

Comment: Also Async and Await. Upgrade and make your life comfy!

Comment: You named your Namespace "Mixin" -> for mixin-functionality, you might check here: http://www.vb-paradise.de/allgemeines/tipps-tricks-und-tutorials/allgemein/58834-oop-theorie-wie-bekommen-interfaces-eigenen-code-oder-mixin-klasse-in-vb-net/#post463924 . It's german, but you can click the expander button (plus sign) to see a piece of code that simulates mixin in (vb).Net

Comment: Ich kann auch Deutsch verstehen :) However forget that I call it mixin. I'm really specifically interested in file scoped extension methods. I'll look at the article anyway. Ta!